# get json of an array of object in swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I would like to get the json of an array of objects in swift

```
class action {
    var ts: Int;
    var winner: Int;
    var meta: [Int: String];

    init(ts : Int, winner: Int, meta: [Int: String]) {
        self.ts = ts;
        self.winner = winner;
        self.meta = meta;
    }
}

var actions:[action] = []

let thisAction = action(ts: 123, winner: 1, meta: [:]);
actions.append(thisAction);

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder();
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(actions);
```

But I have the following error:

> Fatal error: Array<action> does not conform to Encodable because action does not conform to Encodable.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.74.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift, line 3962

Comment: You didn't say `class action : Encodable`, so guess what, it is not encodable thru JSONEncoder. [And please, call it `Action`, not `action`. It's a class.]

Comment: See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, you need to inherit `Codable` on your `Action` class.

```
class Action: Codable {
    var ts: Int
    var winner: Int
    var meta: [Int: String]

    init(ts : Int, winner: Int, meta: [Int: String]) {
        self.ts = ts
        self.winner = winner
        self.meta = meta
    }
}
```

Hint 1: use capital `A` on your `Action` class

Hint 2: Don´t use `;`, no need for that in Swift

Hint 3: use do-try-catch:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(actions)
    print(jsonData)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```